# Set unique IDs which start from zero in R data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, unique, tidyverse

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
column1
 1
 1
 2
 3
 3
```

and I would like to give a unique ID to each element. My problem is that I can not
find a way the unique IDs to start from zero and be like this

```
column1 column2
 1        0
 1        0
 2        1
 3        2
 3        2
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The two `column1` differ in your sample data. Anyway, you can try inserting a `-1` when you create the groups

Comment: thank you @RicS I will change that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `match`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     mutate(column2 = match(column1, unique(column1)) - 1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(column1 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: that's a pretty neat solution as well. Thank you @akrun

Answer (score 3):

Try this, `cur_group_id` from `dplyr` will create the id from 1 but you can easily make it to start from zero:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
df <- structure(list(column1 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-5L))
#Mutate
df %>% group_by(column1) %>% mutate(id=cur_group_id()-1)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   column1 [4]
  column1    id
    <int> <dbl>
1       0     0
2       1     1
3       2     2
4       3     3
5       3     3
```

Comment: Still using `dplyr`, there is a slightly shorter way: `df$column2 <- group_indices(df, column1) - 1`